# Python input to play again or exit not working

Tags: python

So, i wanted to test what i remember of python and i did a very small guess the fruit game. I put a input that whenever somebody writes yes he tries again and if he writes no the game closes. But whenever i write either yes or no it says sorry i didnt get that type again (no matter how many times i write yes/no it says the same)

```
import random


x = ["banana", "pineapple", "mango"]

def restart():
    al = ['yes', 'no']
    r = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no with lower case letters): ").lower
    if r == "yes":
      game()
    elif r == "no":
      exit()
    else:
      print("Sorry i didn't get that.")
      restart()
    

 

def game():
 global guesses
 guesses = 0
 y = input("Guess the fruit: ")
 z = random.choice(x)


 if y == z:
    
    guesses +=1
    print("Your answer was correct, you now have:", guesses)
 else:
     print("Your answer was wrong, you now have:", guesses)
     restart()


game()
```

I put a input that whenever somebody writes yes he tries again and if he writes no the game closes. But whenever i write either yes or no it says sorry i didnt get that type again (no matter how many times i write yes/no it says the same)

Thanks everybody, all i did was remove the .lower and it was fixed!!

Comment: Typo. `lower` without parenthesis to call the function will never equal a string

Comment: You should also consider using a while loop, not recursion (calling game/restart function over again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use parentheses for the .lower() method. Also it’s better to use a while loop(called the game loop for games) for your purpose rather than calling functions repeatedly. Modified code:

```
import random

x = ["banana", "pineapple", "mango"]
al = ['yes', 'no']

#Create a while loop
while True:
    r = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no with lower case letters): ").lower() #Add parentheses 
    if r == "yes":
      game()
    elif r == "no":
      break #Break out of the loop 
      exit()
    else:
      print("Sorry i didn't get that.")
    
def game():
 global guesses
 guesses = 0
 y = input("Guess the fruit: ")
 z = random.choice(x)

 if y == z:
    guesses +=1
    print("Your answer was correct, you now have:", guesses)
 else:
     print("Your answer was wrong, you now have:", guesses)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a set of parentheses after `r = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no with lower case letters): ").lower`. `string.lower()` is a function, not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parenthesis for your `.lower` method. Here's the correct code:

```
import random


x = ["banana", "pineapple", "mango"]

def restart():
    al = ['yes', 'no']
    r = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no with lower case letters): ").lower()
    if r == "yes":
      game()
    elif r == "no":
      exit()
    else:
      print("Sorry i didn't get that.")
      restart()
    

 

def game():
 global guesses
 guesses = 0
 y = input("Guess the fruit: ")
 z = random.choice(x)


 if y == z:
    
    guesses +=1
    print("Your answer was correct, you now have:", guesses)
 else:
     print("Your answer was wrong, you now have:", guesses)
     restart()


game()
```

Comment: i just removed .lower entirely it was pointless.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly what you want to do, the answer is this. If not, there is a mistake. you wrote "lower" without the brackets

.lower()

Comment: When i get the input
'r = input("Do you want to play again (yes/no with lower case letters): ").lower()'
I want to type "yes" and then the game function to run again and let me guess another fruit